# How to redirect (downgrade) from https to http

Tags: apache, http, redirect, https

My main server is currently down. While I'm trying to resolve this issue, I got a temp server up and running -- but it doesn't support https. (Or rather, I don't want to migrate the SSL certificate, only to move it back)

I want to redirect users from https to plain old http, so I added this line to my /etc/sites-available/mysite.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access https://example.com/, my browser can't connect. I get no response. ("site not found" error)

I tried disabling the firewall (`ufw disable`), but it still doesn't work, so I know that's not the issue.

Do modern browsers block a https-to-http downgrade? I thought it would at least display a warning... am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do modern browsers block a https-to-http downgrade?

They might warn about it, but you're missing the crucial point: in order to *see* the downgrade redirect, a browser first has to connect through https. *This* connection *requires* a valid certificate.

So if all you want to avoid is to bring your certificate: you need one. Either get a new one (price is starting at 0, tools are free and available everywhere by default), or bring your existing one.

And the VirtualHost that you configure won't work, because the browser expects https on port 443, not http.

Comment: So, I just created a https certificate for my server. It was a lot easier than I thought it would be... thanks so much for your help!

Comment: In case anyone happens to find this via Google, getting a HTTPS certificate takes less than 2 minutes to set up: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04